# FlatList inside ScrollView not scrolling

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, nestedscrollview

I have a requirement where profile data will be on the top and the feed will come after that. While scrolling the feed, the profile part also should scroll. Means the whole page needs to scroll.

So I have implemented FlatList inside ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={this.state.feed}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          refreshControl={this.refreshControl()}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderItem(item, index)}
          numColumns={2}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.4}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore.bind(this)} />
</ScrollView>
```

But I'm not able to scroll the page.

If I remove the contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}, then handleLoadMore function calling itself continuously.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}
        scrollEventThrottle={200}
        directionalLockEnabled={true}
    >
 <FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={this.state.feed}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          refreshControl={()=>this.refreshControl()}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderItem(item, index)}
          numColumns={2}
          ListFooterComponent={(e)=>this.renderFooter.bind(e)}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.4}
          onEndReached={(e)=>this.handleLoadMore.bind(e)} />



use Callback like this. //

()=>this.yourFUNC()

or

this.yourFUNC()
```

Comment: In this case, scrolling enabled. But handleLoadMore() has been called continuously. Because of the absence of flex: 1

Comment: With arrow function and bind(), the handleLoadMore() has not been called even once. without bind, it has called multiple times.

Comment: you can try to Call alert() in those functions and try

Comment: Hey, thanks!. But the same behavior will happen If we add an alert also. The alert will come multiple times.

Comment: okay Can you add your file and JSON data, i will let you know whats the problem here